# Slow Execution of an ASP.NET Web Page

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have a web page which brings 13K+ records in 20 seconds. There is a menu on the page, clicking on which navigates me to another page which is very lightweight. Displaying the data (13K+) took only 20 seconds whereas navigating from that page took much longer, more than 2 minutes. Can you tell me why the latter is taking so much time? I've stopped the page_load  code execution on click of the menu.

I've disabled the viewstate for that page as well.

---

I am stopping the page load when menu is clicked by finding out what triggered the postback, if it is the menu item then the code is not executed.

```
if(!IsPostBack || (IsPostBack && request.params["Event_Target"].Contains("TreeView1")))
{
    //Code goes here..
}
```

I am using IE 6.0.
Only after the first page finishes loading, I'll be able to scroll through the page. 
Second page loads few labels and text boxes, no processing on page_load.

I am not sure where exactly the time is spent because if I move between two light pages, then it's pretty fast, but if I load a huge resultset on a page and then I try to move to some other page, it takes unusually long.

Comment: Which web browser are you talking about?

Comment: How are you stopping page_load when you click?  
How are you doing your timings?    
How do you know that the first page finished loading?    
What is the second page actually doing?     
Where is the time spent when loading the second page? (on the server or on the client?)

Answer (score 0):

I just placed ajax update panel on my page and what a difference. Navigating to the other page takes less than 2 seconds.